# WPF Media element Get Video Name

Tags: c#, wpf, video

When using wpf's media element to play a video; is it possible to get the name (metadata) of the video that was loaded? I now know it's not possible get the frame number of the video, I just want to know if the same is true for the filename. 
I am trying to save (in the database) the video name together with the processed frame for trace-ability and i'm stuck here.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question makes no sense... surely you are loading video files into your `MediaElement` in order to play them... can you not just read the name of the file when you do this?

Comment: Also, if you use a `MediaPlayer` instead, you should be able to use the `MediaPlayer.Position` property to show the current playing position.

Comment: #grin Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog videoOpenFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); videoOpenFileDialog has a file name property #BlondMoment . . .Thanks!

Comment: Please leave out the hash tags... they are not required, or appreciated here... this is not twitter. So, did that solve your problem?

Comment: I'll leave them out but what harm do they cause? and yes it solved my issue

Comment: WPF does not expose a way to retrieve such metadata. Instead, you must use unmanaged Windows Media Player APIs to access this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to play an audio or video file in a `MediaElement`, you must first load the file. Therefore, as you access to the file, you can just read the name of the file at that stage.

Also, if you use a [`MediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object instead, you should be able to use the [`MediaPlayer.Position` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show the current playing position of the file.